# Filter a dataframe of annual values of two groups to the common period between both groups and subgroups in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataframe of annual values for two top-level groups, and multiple subgroups. I need the years outside of the common period to be filtered out within each subgroup, so that I'm only left with the common period between the two top-level groups in each subgroup.

In other words, my dataframe looks like this:

```
Group    Subgroup    Year
  A          1       1901
  A          1       1902
  A          1       1903
  A          1       1904
  B          1       1902
  B          1       1903
  B          1       1904
  B          1       1905
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
Group    Subgroup    Year
  A          1       1902
  A          1       1903
  A          1       1904
  B          1       1902
  B          1       1903
  B          1       1904
```

I also have a dataframe (named "years" below) that has the range of years for each subgroup:

```
 Subgroup     GroupA_Min    GroupA_Max    GroupB_Min    GroupB_Max
    1             1901          1904          1902          1905
```

My initial approaches have involved using if/else statements in a for loop (simplified to one condition here):

```
df_trimmed = data.frame(matrix())
for s in unique(df$subgroup){
  subgroup = df[df$subgroup == s,]
  selector = year[s, ]
  if (selector$GroupA_Min < selector GroupB_Min & selector$GroupA_Max < selector$GroupB_Max{
    subgroup = subset(subgroup, Year >= selector$GroupB_Min & Year <= selector$GroupA_Max) 
  df_trimmed = rbind(df_trimmed, subgroup)
```

However, this is not producing the correct common periods across groups, so I'm wondering if there's a better approach or if I am missing something.

Comment: Your example data only has one value for `Subgroup`, it'd be helpful if you can (a) provide data that demonstrates correct behavior with different `Subgroup` values, (b) give `dput()` output instead of (or at least alongside) a visual representation of your data.  It's much easier to load into a local environment that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want the shared years between groups A and B, within each subgroup.  To get this result, group your data by subgroup, then select years which occur in both groups.  Like this:

```r
library(dplyr) 

df %>%
  group_by(sub_group) %>%
  filter(year %in% year[group == "A"],
         year %in% year[group == "B"])
```

Example data (includes two values for `sub_group`):

```r
set.seed(111)
n <- 16
df <- tibble(group = sample(c("A", "B"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
             sub_group = sample(1:2, size = n, replace = TRUE),
             year = c(1901:1908, 1902:1909)) %>%
  arrange(sub_group, group, year)
```

Comment: This appears to work when I do a check on the ranges of years, however if I split the dataframe into the two groups, they are not equal in number of rows. Which should be impossible if the common periods are getting trimmed across all subgroups. So I'm not really sure what's going on there

Comment: One possible explanation is that there are multiple instances of the same year for one group.  That's possible in the way I randomly generated the data.  If that doesn't occur in your real data, then I agree, you shouldn't see an unequal number of rows per group, once this operation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. For each `Year` and `Subgroup` combination, filter to include where the number of distinct `Group` for a `Year` is equal to number distinct `Group` for the entire data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Year, Subgroup) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Group) == n_distinct(.$Group))
```

**Output**

```
  Group Subgroup  Year
  <chr>    <int> <int>
1 A            1  1902
2 A            1  1903
3 A            1  1904
4 B            1  1902
5 B            1  1903
6 B            1  1904
```

Comment: That's a great way to look at the problem and come up with a solution! I've just wondered if you can generalise it to more than 1 subgroup (as stated in the question). You could also group by the `Subgroup`, but is there then a way to access the data one grouping level less?

Comment: @starja Great point, thanks. It seems that including `Subgroup` within the `group_by` would address that and give appropriate results, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: I think you're right and I had a too complicated scenario in mind; the OP stated that there are 2 top level groups (I somehow thought the number of groups depends on the `Subgroup`). So you could theoretically substitute `n_distinct(.$Group)` with `2` and it still works

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking for something like `dplyr::filter` using `dplyr::between` for the year column?

Your data

```
df <-
read.delim(text="Group Subgroup Year
A 1 1901
A 1 1902
A 1 1903
A 1 1904
B 1 1902
B 1 1903
B 1 1904
B 1 1905")  %>% tidyr::separate("Group.Subgroup.Year",
                                into=c("Group", "Subgrouop", "Year"), sep=" ")
```

```
df %>% filter(between(Year, 1902, 1905))
```

produces

```
  Group Subgrouop Year
1     A         1 1902
2     A         1 1903
3     A         1 1904
4     B         1 1902
5     B         1 1903
6     B         1 1904
7     B         1 1905
```

If you want to programmatically get the 1902 and 1905 values, you can do:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(Group) %>%
 summarise(min_year = min(Year),
           max_year = max(Year)) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 summarise(from = max(min_year),
           to = min(max_year)) -> ranges

# now use filter with
filter(df, Year, ranges$from, ranges$to)
```